# Implement mock service with wsdl tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm currently following this tutorial to learn how to implement a mock web service:
http://iandykes.blogspot.nl/2008/06/creating-mock-web-services-in-net.html

The web service that i'm using is a public web service: http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

So i used the `wsdl.exe` tool to generate a class for that service, like it is explained in the tutorial. I also added the generated `.cs` file to my Solution project.

I then did the following in Visual Studio to add the Web Service:

`Right clicked on my project -> Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference`

In there i added the URL to the web service and then hit the `Add Reference` button. So now i have a `Web References` folder in my project with a `CurrencyProxy` in it (that is how i named it).

The next step that i have to do according to the tutorial is:

> In the code behind for this Web Service, change the class definition
>   so that it implements the interface in the generated code.

That is where i'm actually stuck. Where can i find the code behind file of the Web Service? I'm not sure what to do here.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

When you add Web Service to your project, there will be *YourWebService.asmx* and *YourWebService.asmx.cs* under it. In *YourWebService.asmx.cs*, just replace `System.Web.Services.WebService` with your interface, which was generated earlier. Implement this interface as you wish and that's it, mock service's done.